# Hide the divs starting with same word

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide the divs which are starting with same letter. These divs comes dynamically.

```
$('div[id^="treeDiv"]').each(function() {
    // here i need to hide the divs starting with "treeDiv" 
});
```

How to do it. Please give me suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: you don't need `each` for that.

Comment: what do you means by "divs starting with same letter" ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('div[id^="treeDiv"]').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks.. it is hiding. but back the scenes that white space remains as same. How to eliminate that white space also. is there any other method?

Comment: I think that is another question, for which you will need to provide some markup and CSS for us to review.

Answer (score 0):

Or possibly set it as a function:

```
function hideMe(container){
    $('div[id^="'+container+'"]').hide();
}
```